# Stuck at passing JSON as argument in bash

Tags: bash, json, arguments

I know many have asked similar questions, but I can't make it work.

I have a file called `Dependencies`:

```
Accounts
Aggregates
Blog
Configuration
Contacts
Contents
DataTypes
Forms
Geo
Globalization
Media
Modules
Navigation
Podcast
Seo
Social
Taxonomy
Tracking
Vlog
```

And I have this code to turn it into a JSON array string:

```
DependenciesPath=/$Organization/Common/Dependencies
mapfile -t DependenciesArray < $DependenciesPath
DependenciesArray+=('Infra')
export dependencies=$(echo '%s\n' "${DependenciesArray[@]}" | jq -R . | jq -s .)
```

Then I have this code to pass it to `node.js`:

```
node /$Organization/$Repository/LocalizationHelper.js $File $astFile "$dependencies"
```

The problem is that I get this in my `LocalizationHelper.js` file:

```
[
  "%s\\n Accounts Aggregates Blog Configuration Contacts Contents DataTypes Forms Geo Globalization Media Modules Navigation Podcast Seo Social Taxonomy Tracking Vlog Infra"
]
```

As you can see items are not separate from each other and that `%s\\n`  is also redundant at the beginning. Those is what I want (a valid JSON array):

```
[ "Accounts", "Aggregates", "Blog", ...]
```

I'm stuck here. What should I do? I want to use `const dependencies = JSON.parse(process.argv[4])` to convert it into a JavaScript Array in my code.

Comment: `echo '%s\n' "${DependenciesArray[@]}"`? Did you mean to use `printf`?

Answer (score 10):

You could use `jq` to transform your file directly. No need to use `mapfile` or generate a shell array:

```
jq -Rn '[ inputs, "Infra" ]' </path/to/Dependencies
```

Example:

```
printf '%s\n' apple banana cherry |
    jq -Rn '[ inputs, "Infra" ]'
```

output:

```
[
  "apple",
  "banana",
  "cherry",
  "Infra" 
]
```

The `-R` tells `jq` to read raw (unquoted) data, and `-n` tells `jq` not to read any input "before" the pipeline - leaving it for the `inputs` operator to process itself at the appropriate point.

You can compress the output into a single line by adding the `-c` flag:

```
["apple","banana","cherry","Infra"]
```

Answer (score 3):

`jq` is usually my go-to tool for any JSON processing, and Chris Davies is giving a good example of `jq` applied to this particular issue [in their answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/758636/116858).

[Another tool, called `jo`,](https://jpmens.net/2016/03/05/a-shell-command-to-create-json-jo/) is made specifically for *constructing JSON on the command line*.  With `jo`, the JSON array can be had as the string `$deps` from the following short shell code:

```bash
deps=$( jo -a <Dependencies )
```

Adding an `Infra` as a final element in the array can be done like so:

```bash
deps=$( jo -a <Dependencies | jo -f - "Infra" )
```

With the data given in the question, this would produce the following JSON array as a string in `$deps`:

```json
["Accounts","Aggregates","Blog","Configuration","Contacts","Contents","DataTypes","Forms","Geo","Globalization","Media","Modules","Navigation","Podcast","Seo","Social","Taxonomy","Tracking","Vlog","Infra"]
```

Add `-p` to the last invocation of `jo` to generate a pretty-printed array.

---

Please also be aware of some of the limitations of this tool. The following is a comment from Stéphane Chazelas:

> Beware it treats number-looking strings as numbers, empty strings as `null`, `[...]` as arrays, `@file` would load the contents of a file, etc (see for instance `printf '%s\n' 1e002 @/etc/shadow @/dev/watchdog 0xDEADBEEF '' '{}' | jo -a`). It can't be used that way for arbitrary strings.

Comment: Beware it treats number-looking strings as numbers, empty strings as `null`, `[...]` as arrays, `@file` would load the contents of a file, etc (see for instance `printf '%s\n' 1e002 @/etc/shadow @/dev/watchdog 0xDEADBEEF '' '{}' | jo -a`). It can't be used that way for arbitrary strings.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in a [nushell](https://www.nushell.sh/):

```
open dependencies.txt | lines | to json
```

If you want to remain in bash/zsh, you can also use nushell instead of jq:

```
nu -c 'open dependencies.txt | lines | to json'
```

Answer (score 0):

With `perl`:

```
$ perl -CiI -MJSON::PP -le '
    chomp(@lines = <>);
    print encode_json [@lines, "Infra"]' Dependencies
["Accounts","Aggregates","Blog","Configuration","Contacts","Contents","DataTypes","Forms","Geo","Globalization","Media","Modules","Navigation","Podcast","Seo","Social","Taxonomy","Tracking","Vlog","Infra"]
```

With the input decoded in UTF-8, and encoded *by `encode_json`* (not the STDOUT output layer which should remain in byte/latin1 mode) to produce UTF-8 encoded JSON.

Or if using the OO interface, you can skip those decoding and encoding:

```
perl -MJSON::PP -le '
  chomp(@lines = <>);
  print JSON::PP->new->encode([@lines, "Infra"])' Dependencies
```

Which will pass the bytes > 127 as-is. It won't choke on non-UTF-8 input, but would produce non-UTF-8 JSON in those cases.

To decode the input as per the locale's character encoding and output UTF-8 encoded JSON:

```
perl -MJSON::PP -Mopen=IN,locale -le '
  chomp(@lines = <>);
  print encode_json [@lines, "Infra"]' Dependencies
```

You can also produce JSON where non-ASCII characters are represented as `\uXXXX` (or `\uDXXXX\uDXXXX` for those above U+FFFF as usual):

```
perl -MJSON::PP -Mopen=IN,locale -le '
  chomp(@lines = <>);
  print JSON::PP->new->ascii->encode([@lines, "Infra"])' Dependencies
```

If the input contains only ASCII characters like in your sample, that won't make any difference, but that's something you may have to take into account if there may be non-English dependency names.